# Need to generate random data for Highcharts series

Tags: random, highcharts

I'm trying to generate some random data points for my Highcharts series, but I'm having issues with the data function. Here's my code (simplified from [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnTqS/1/)):

```
series : {
    name : 'Total Mentions',
    type:'spline',
    lineWidth:1,
    data : (function() {
        var arr = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            var date = randomDate(new Date(2004, 0, 9), new Date());
            var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
            var finalDate = "Date.UTC(" + date.getFullYear() + ", " + date.getDate() + ", " + date.getMonth() + ")";
            arr.push([finalDate, randNum]);
        }
        return arr;
    })()
},
[...etc...],
```

The format that should be coming out should look like this:

```
[Date.UTC(2008, 23, 8),56], 
[Date.UTC(2012, 12, 6),21],
[Date.UTC(2008, 22, 10),16],
[Date.UTC(2009, 17, 7),25],
[...etc...],
```

Right now, my page isn't loading the chart. The page will load infinitely, as if it's not recognizing the data.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Take a look the api demos, there's a demo which use random time, you can try to understand how it works and do it for dates. http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/dynamic-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should push date in millisec in array, like this;

```
   arr.push([date.getTime(), randNum]);
   arr.sort(function (a,b) { if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1; if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1; 
   return 0; })  
   return arr;
```

I've created a fiddle at; http://jsfiddle.net/hkskoglund/cnTqS/4/

Try catching other syntax errors in the console in Chrome devtools.